# How to generate a tree of commits relations from a set of git patches?

Tags: git, git-log

I have a set of patches that apply to an old parent in a repo, I would like to generate a tree that represents time/dependency relationship between these patches.

For a directory containing such files:

```
0001-add-foo.patch
0002-add-bar.patch
0003-fix-bar.patch
0004-fix-foo.patch
0005-repair-x.patch
```

Make something like this:

```
├*    sha...    commit msg...
├─┬*  sha...    commit msg...
│ ├*  sha...    commit msg...
├─┼*  sha...    commit msg...
│ └*  sha...    commit msg...
├*    sha...    commit msg...
└*    sha...    commit msg...
```

I can not guuarantee that patches have no conflicts, but I do know that all patches apply to some specific parent commit in the repo or to other patches

Answer (score -1):

Maybe i misunderstood your problem but only with gitkraken, it should do the trick :)